# How to manage and organize 'requests' for website updates from a variety of departments: To Do List

Tags: content, change-management

I am taking on the responsibility of managing two websites (Wordpress) for nonprofit societies. I receive multiple requests for mini-content changes from a variety of committees and departments. As a volunteer, I'm hoping to park these requests into a chart or to do list that I can then use to work through a slew of easy, one minute content changes all in one go.

I considered creating an excel sheet for this, but then thought that the professionals on PW.SE might be able to point to a template or to-do-tracking system that is already done up and better thought out than what I could cob together.

When it's time to work, I need to direct myself to the page that needs updating, input/upload the desired changes, and then check it off the list.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility would be a bug tracking / issue tracking software like [BugZilla](http://www.bugzilla.org/) or [Mantis](http://www.mantisbt.org/), to name just two of quite a long list of available systems. Many project management systems like [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) (or one of its forks like [ChiliProject](https://www.chiliproject.org/)) or [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) offer ticket trackers as well, along with internal wikis, time tracking and a lot of other stuff.

Another possibility would be a system that implements the [Getting Things Done](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getting_Things_Done) philosophy. There's quite a selection of those out there, too. I personally came to prefer [Tracks](http://getontracks.org/).

All the systems I mentioned need to run on a server. Maybe you can get a little space for your administration, maybe under a subdomain like issues.your-domain.org or something to that effect. You also need to consider which server-side technology you've got available. Because the sites are using Wordpress, PHP should be available. If you prefer systems build with other technologies like Ruby on Rails (Redmine, Tracks) or Python (Trac), you might want to talk to your hosting provider.

Of course, there are a bunch of issue tracking systems and GTD-oriented To-Do-Lists for the desktop as well. I personally prefer the server way, so I don't know to much about those.